# error de sql con php

Tags: php, sql

quiero conectar sql server con php , tengo el siguiente error:

> ******ConexiÃ³n no se pudo establecer. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server [2]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11
>   for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to
>   SQL Server [2]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1]
>   => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11
>   for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001
>   [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error
>   has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is
>   not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more
>   information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error
>   has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is
>   not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more
>   information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )******

ya descargue el ODBC , ya configure el php.ini, este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"prueba", "UID"=>"JhonaJM", "PWD"=>"Inicio.123");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tu instancia de SQL Server tenga un nombre de instancia?  Si instalaste SQL Server Express si cambiarle nada, deberías conectare a "localhost\SQLExpress".

Comment: Revisa las indicaciones de [esta guía](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/).